# 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Selected'

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to run this code to get the values from DataGridView to show in the text box when I double click mouse at the row.

```cs
private void dgvUsers_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                //This is the code which helps to show the data when the row is double clicked.
                //The SelectedItem property of RadGridView is used to access the data item of the selected row. It changes its value every time the selected row changes and exposes the object to which the row is bound. 
                DataGridRow dgr = grid.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
                DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)dgr.Item;
                txtUserID.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                txtFirstName.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                txtLastName.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                txtEmail.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                txtUserName.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                txtPassword.Text = dr[5].ToString();
                txtContact.Text = dr[6].ToString();
                txtAddress.Text = dr[7].ToString();
                cmbGender.Text = dr[8].ToString();
                cmbUserType.Text = dr[9].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Text Box show the data. But still have an error.
Error show:-

> 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no accessible extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) - CS1061

I don't know how to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

My DataGrid refence:-

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvUsers"  IsReadOnly="True"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectionMode="Single"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="504" Margin="375,104,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="590"
    MouseDoubleClick="dgvUsers_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Binding on TextBoxes instead copying values in C# code.

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dgvUsers, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Selected property is not in WPF DataGrid. You can use SelectedItem, SelectedItems or SelectedValue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly advise. "Petr Vobornik". Today I open and run code again. Error code don't show anything even though I don't edit code anything.